# Laravel 5.6 Attach Multiple Users (Speakers) with the Event

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I am trying to attach Users list to the events by sending an array of IDs of the users, I have the following table structure in Laravel.

**Events (table)**

```
Schema::create('events', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::table('events', function($table) {
            $table->foreign('organiser_id')->references('id')->on('tutors')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('event_categories')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('city_id')->references('id')->on('cities')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

**Event Users (table)**

```
Schema::create('event_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('event_id')->nullable()->unsigned();
        $table->integer('user_id')->nullable()->unsigned();
        $table->boolean('is_speaker');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
    Schema::table('event_user', function($table) {
        $table->foreign('event_id')->references('id')->on('events')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
    });
```

**Events Controller (Store method)**

```
        $events = new Events;

        $events->organiser_id = $request->user()->id;
        $events->save();

        $speakers = User::find($request->user()->id);
        $speakers->events()->detach();
        $speakers->events()->attach($request->speakers_list, ['is_speaker' => true]);
```

**Event (Model)**

```
public function users(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'users');
    }
```

**User (Model)**

```
public function events(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Events::class, 'event_user', 'event_id', 'user_id')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

when I am trying to attach users with the event, I am getting the following error

> message: "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation:
>
> 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`acp_db`.`event_user`, CONSTRAINT `event_user_event_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`event_id`) REFERENCES `events` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
>
> (SQL: insert into `event_user` (`created_at`, `event_id`, `is_speaker`, `updated_at`, `user_id`) values (2020-03-15 19:49:49, 11, 1, 2020-03-15 19:49:49, 12), (2020-03-15 19:49:49, 11, 1, 2020-03-15 19:49:49, 13))"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are providing a table name of `users` to the `Event::users()` [many-to-many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many). Since you are using proper naming conventions, you don't need any parameters to either relationship definition:

```php
class Event extends Model
{
    public function users() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
}
class User extends Model
{
    public function events() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Event::class);
    }
}
```